Why doesn't the function curves in R plot correctly when they exceed a functions boundry?
Let's say I have probability distribution function from some sort of function within a given boundry. Its total area is of course 1 within this boundry. It's defined as zero outside this boundry.
f <- function(z) 2*z^2 - 15*z + 15
fp <- function(x) f(x) * dunif(x, 10, 30) 
norm_const <- function(func, l=10, u=30) integrate(func, l, u)$value 
norm_pdf <- function(x) fp(x) / norm_const(fp)

Now if we use the curve function in R (or ggplot2's geom_function)
curve(norm_pdf, 0, 40)


As you can see the graphs curve does not go to zero directly at the lower and upper boundry for the value x. I want the plot to act the way like this code below (see red lines). However, I want when the curve hits zero, at both ends, to just become a straight line to infinity. Basically I want to graph to plot the curve as it should! There appears to be some kind of lagging effect on the curve for some reason? When it exceeds its boundry.
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() + geom_function(fun = norm_pdf) + xlab("x") + ylab("Density") + theme_minimal() + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0, 40), breaks=seq(0, 40,2)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 10, y = 0, xend = 10, yend = norm_pdf(10)), color="red") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 30, y = 0, xend = 30, yend = norm_pdf(30)), color="red") 


curve(norm_pdf, 0, 40, n = 1e6)

Ah! Thank you, how does it work in geom_function and/or the ggplot2 package?

stat_function has the same n parameter with the same default.

Ah thanks, I just learned the difference between geom and stats functions in ggplot!

Each geom calls a default stat function.

Strictly speaking, n = 1e6 doesn't solve the problem, it just makes it invisible.  It's a matter of resolution.

@Limey Right, but that is all that matters when plotting. However, you can always not use curve (and e.g. use lines instead) and ensure that the function is evaluated exactly at discontinuities.

In my case, this solves the problem. It was just a matter of plotting

As Roland suggested, this solves it
curve(norm_pdf, 0, 40, n = 1e6)

and for the ggplot2 package the solution is
stat_function(fun = norm_pdf, n=10^6)

One can replace  geom_function with stat_function and it works.
